# Is that any option to separate url in Telegram?

Tags: telegram

Is that anyway to paste multilinks  to telegram that should paste automatilcally separate in telegram messages.

for examples: i have multilinks like

https://links1.com
https://links2.com
https://links3.com

i want to separate message like this...

non capture, [6/22/2023 2:20 AM]
https://links1.com

non capture, [6/22/2023 2:20 AM]
https://links2.com

non capture, [6/22/2023 2:20 AM]
https://links3.com